# inverse of boost::make_function_output_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

The boost function [make_function_output_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) converts a function that would be appropriate for std::for_each into an iterator appropriate for std::copy.  Is there a boost function that does the reverse.  That is, takes an iterator appropriate for std::copy and converts it to a function appropriate for std::for_each.

So if I have an output iterator output_iter.  I need

```
for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), make_output_iterator_function(output_iter));
```

To do the same thing as

```
copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), output_iter);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. The two are fairly different things. There's no output from `std::for_each` at all. Perhaps you're looking for: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/back_insert_iterator.html or `std::transform`? Can you add an example of the first case perhaps and a pseudo example that shows what you want for the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`std::insert_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/insert_iterator/) or [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) are what you are looking for?

You can bind `std::insert_iterator::operator=`, which does an insert on every invocation, with some `boost::bind` sorcery:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

    typedef std::vector<int> Container;
    typedef std::insert_iterator< Container > InsertIt;

int main(){
    Container v1, v2;
    InsertIt insert_it (v2,v2.end());
    std::for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
            boost::bind(static_cast<InsertIt& (InsertIt::*)(typename Container::const_reference)>(&InsertIt::operator=), insert_it, _1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class

```
 template<typename T>
 struct iterator_to_function {
      T iter_;
      iterator_to_function(const T& iter) : iter_(iter) {}
      template<typename T2>
      T& operator()(const T2& elem) {*iter_=elem; return ++iter_;}
 };

template<class T>
iterator_to_function<T> make_iterator_function(const T& iter) 
{
  return iterator_to_function<T>(iter);
}
```

Converts an output iterator to a unary function.

```
typedef vector<int> t_vec;
t_vec v;
t_vec v2;
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), 
         make_iterator_function(back_inserter(v2));
```

Comment: If the iterator is (for example) just a pointer this won't work will it? The output iterator needs to be incremented between assignments for the general case I thought.

Comment: @awoodland you are right.  The ++ is ignored for the standard containers, but std::copy should also work for raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option I'd do this with lambdas rather than `std/boost::bind`, e.g.:

```
std::vector<type> v1;
std::for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end() [&output_iter](const type& t) {*output_iter++ = t});
```

Of course it would make more sense to just use `std::copy` in the first place!