# binding an assignment operator to a boost::function object

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 project where I would like to use a `boost::function` object to set the value of a pointer. Something like this:

```
boost::function< void( int* ) > SetValue;
boost::function< int*() > GetValue;

int* my_value_;
SetValue = boost::bind( my_value_, _1 ); // how should this look?
GetValue = boost::bind( my_value_ ); // and this?

int v;
SetValue( &v );
assert( my_value_ == &v );

int* t = GetValue();
assert( t == my_value_ );
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need an intermediate function like:

```
void DoSetValue( int* s, int* v ) { s = v; };
SetValue = boost::bind( DoSetValue, my_value_, _1 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `bind` to work that way, you would need a pointer to `operator=( int* )`. Of course, there is no such thing, so you need an intermediate function.

If you could use `lambda` or `phoenix`, there are ways to make a function-object that assigns something to something else. It depends on which library you use, but it would look somewhat like this:

```
bl::var( my_value_ ) = bl::_1;
```

Comment: boost::phoenix looks like it could be a good solution, but I'm having trouble understanding from the docs how to use it in this situation.
For example: `SetValue = boost::phoenix::val( my_value_ );` doesn't seem to do anything when SetValue() is invoked later.

Comment: Try something like `boost::phoenix::val( my_value_ ) = phoenix_placeholder::_1`

Comment: Yes, but how do I get that in to the function pointer `SetValue`?

Comment: Doesn't just `SetValue = ( boost::phoenix::val( my_value_ ) = phoenix_placeholder::_1 )` works?

Comment: It compiles and runs, but has no effect on the value.

Answer (score 2):

Use Boost.Lambda library:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::function<void(int*)> SetValue = (boost::lambda::var(my_value) = boost::lambda::_1);
    boost::function<int*()> GetValue = boost::lambda::var(my_value);
}
```

You can find more about using variables [in its documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.delaying_constants_and_variables).

Comment: Ah, so *that's* why the assignment operator associates right-to-left ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I should've placed braces around this expression :)

Comment: Also, if you will use a class, you can bind to the `operator=`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10573795/13767) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt will not work as `bind()` requires a function (or functor), but you are passing a data pointer, so you need to provide a function that does the work you seek.

*Note*: if you use C++11, you could use lambdas, to avoid having to create a named function

*Note*: you need to dereference the pointers in `DoSetValue` or use references (in which case you need to change the declaration of `SetValue` as well) -- otherwise the change will not be visible outside the function call

```
void DoSetValue( int& s, int& v ) { s = v; };
```